# How to configure php.ini file

Tags: php, configuration, session-cookies, ini

I am having a bit of trouble understanding how to set up the php.ini file on my website. I have included the line `session.cookie_lifetime = 1800` as well as some others, but nothing has changed. When I go to my phpinfo.php pgae, none of the settings I have configured in the .ini file are not taken into effect. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make changes in the `php.ini` file you have to restart the webserver or reloading the configuration files in most cases.

Because I have not enough reputation yet to write comments I assume you are using a LAMP environment. You can restart the webserver by typing in console:

```
service apache2 restart
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

`reload` or `force-reload` instead of `restart` should also work for just reloading the configuration files, but with `restart` you're one the safe side.

Also make sure you're editing the correct `php.ini` file. You can find the right file by looking at the 'Loaded Configuration File' directive of `phpinfo()` output.

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines in `.htaccess` file, it will increase the timeout to 30 minutes.

```
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 1800
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1800
```

Comment: I did what you said, but now I'm getting an Internal Server Error.